# Pale lmtt fonts and can't be made in italics or bold

Tags: fonts, text

[image]

I am writing a document whereby I need to differentiate some text from other. In the above example, I want to differentiate the text *‘password1’* and *‘s723ja0xp*’ from the remaining text. I used the commands `{\fontfamily{lmtt9}\selectfont\large password1}` and `{\fontfamily{lmtt9}\selectfont\large s723ja0xp}` }, which worked. However, both *password1* and *s723ja0xp* are paler than the remaining text. Is there a way to fix this, please? Also, is there a way to make *password1* and *s723ja0xp* in italics? I have tried the commands `{\fontfamily{lmtt9}\selectfont\large\textit {password1}}` and `{\fontfamily{lmtt9}\selectfont\large\itshape {password1}}` but they all failed.

Comment: What is your main font?

Comment: You should give a MWE.

Comment: @Clara the main font is Arial and i used the commands \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}  and \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}  to set the document's fonts

Comment: You have not shown any code we can test. in `\fontfamily{lmtt9}`  this selects that family but how have you defined the `lmtt9` family?

Comment: "the main font is Arial and i used the commands `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}` " those statements are contradictory, `phv` is not Arial. With no example in the question it is hard to help here or guess the problem.

Comment: @David what code do you wnat me to show please? Can you please specif so I'll post it here.

Comment: @JonathanCassar Please make a small, but compilable test document. People should be able to copy & paste it and reproduce your problem without having to make any modifications to the code.

Comment: post a small but complete document that produces the output you show. You are using some non standard family lmtt9 but have not shown how it is defined or how to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear as you provided no example but lm typewriter is available in slanted and slanted bold.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}% Helvetica (clone)
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}
\begin{document}
is incorrect because
\texttt{\large password1}
\texttt{\slshape\large password2}
\texttt{\slshape\bfseries\large password3}
is weaker than ...
\end{document}
```